# Can't update Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

I have been trying to update jenkins from 2.203 to 2.277 and got the error below. We are using Windows Server 2008 R2. How to fix this error?

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching updates.jenkins.io found.
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:191)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:93)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:436)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:200)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1508)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:198)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1958)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:322)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1526)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:215)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1024)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:954)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1065)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1384)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1412)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1396)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that you have to enable SNI extension. Open your jenkins.xml and change:

```
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080</arguments>
```

to

```
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=true -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080</arguments>
```

Restart Jenkins service